# Sharing a USB printer securely

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, printer

I have a printer on a server connected via a USB on Windows 8. I allowed it to share the printer. However, I could only find it after I went under the network and went into that computer and typed in the main user/pass.

Is there a way to share without having to login to that user and is it safe and secure to do that?

Would it be best to maybe create a lower level user and then login with that user to access the printer for more security?

Comment: Does [this answer for XP](http://superuser.com/questions/27711/sharing-a-printer-over-a-lan-without-making-a-guest-account) help?

Answer (score 0):

To share it without login you will have to enable guest account.
This is unsecure for a few reasons: guest accont has no password and if someone have physical access to your server, he can login to it using guest account. Also, depending on how you created them, your network shares may have read\write permission for "All" which is also includes guest account. Nothing that can't be dealt with, but attention should be given